# How to find Frenzy forum homepage on my Joomla site?

Tags: joomla, module

I am a noob to joomla migrating from drupal. I found a nice forum module called [Frenzy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum/7620?qh=YToyOntpOjA7czo1OiJmb3J1bSI7aToxO3M6NjoiZm9ydW1zIjt9). Its administration menu is nice but I am not able to find the forum page itself. I searched the menus for a hidden link but couldn't find it. I know that joomla is not the same as drupal that's why I am asking here. Where can I find the homepage of the module ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the link to the Frenzy module you provided is no longer working, although I suspect that this is not actually a module but rather a component.

If that is right, then you need to create a menu item for this component - to do this go to the relevant menu and click on the "new" icon (green plus, top right). The frenzy component should appear on the next screen for you to select from.

If it is actually a module, then you will need to publish it to a valid module position within your template, using the module manager function under the extensions menu.

Hope this helps! As the frenzy link is no longer working, I can recomend the [Kunena](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/forum/7256)
component which you can obtain from this link.